# KornShell telling me "unknown format specifier"

Tags: ksh

I'm getting unknown format specifier
Code is

```
space=(($RANDOM % 99) + 1 )
printf "%$space /n" $char
```

Char being previously defined

Can anyone help?

Comment: You specified a width but not a type %42d, %99.3f, etc

Comment: Also, you need to use arithmetic expansion: `space=$(( ($RANDOM % 99 ) + 1 ))` -- the outer double brackets are not mathematical, they're syntax `$(( math_expr ))`

Answer (score 2):

1. Change `/` to `\`: `printf "test \n" $char`
2. Use a defined format like `'%*s \n'`
3. Make the count of spaces variable in printf: `printf '%*s \n' "$space"`
4. Quote your variables. Use `"$char"` instead of `$char`

Example:

```
space=22; char=a; printf "%*s \n" "$space" "$char"
```

Then, make sure the value of space is a number, use `$((…))`:

```
space=$(( ($RANDOM % 99) + 1 ))
```

Or, simpler:

```
char=a; printf "%*s \n" "$(( ($RANDOM % 99) + 1 ))" "$char"
```